# Let $\{u_1, u_2,\ldots u_n\} $be a linearly independent subset of $\Bbb R^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

let $x$ be in $\Bbb R^n$ such that $u_1^Tx=\cdots=u_n^Tx=0$. Show that $x=0$.

Im not sure how to do this. I know that if you show it is nonsingular that would suffice but I dont know how to do that either. Any help with this proof would be great. And an explanation so I can understand each step, if possible!
Thanks.

Comment: What's $T$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: oh I am sorry, T is the transpose

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the family $(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^n$ since it's linearly independent and has the cardinality $n=\dim\Bbb R^n$ hence the there's $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\Bbb R$ such that

$$x=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k u_k$$
hence
$$||x||^2=\langle x ,x\rangle=\left\langle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k u_k ,x\right\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\langle u_k ,x\rangle=0\implies x=0$$

Comment: how can you say that x= that summation?

Comment: The $x_k$'s are the coordinate of the vector $x$ in the basis $(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$.

Comment: Im still not sure I quite understand how that last summation implies that x=0

Comment: We proved that $||x||=0$ so $x=0$.

Comment: but how can you say ||x|| equals zero. I am sorry i think i am a little lost on that

Comment: and how come you didnt use the transpose

Comment: By the hypothesis we have $\langle u_k,x\rangle= u_k^T x=0$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$ so
$$||x||^2=\sum_{k=1}^nx_k \underbrace{\langle u_k,x\rangle}_{=0}=0$$
so we conclude that $x=0$.